# Creating image planes for 3d character modeling, but front reference is not straight on

Tags: 3d

I'm using images from 3d.sk to do some character modeling but I'm having trouble setting up the front image in Photoshop. The model's head in the photosgraph is turned slightly to the side. I tried messing around with lens correction but didn't really know what I was doing. How can I fix this image to make it better for 3d modeling?

Comment: that is not possible image is not a 3d model. And in the end whatever you do it will look messed up unless you can paint the newly revealed side of the face really good

Comment: The edit to the title by @Yisela significantly changes the question, and IMO not in a good way: my answer (if I had to give one) to the original question would've simply been "_It depends on the 3D software you're using; check the manual._" To the new question, as phrased in the current title, it's "_You can't. It's impossible._" Admittedly neither of those are very helpful answers, but at least the original question _could_ in principle get a better answer from someone else. Frankly, I'm tempted to revert the title to the original one.

Comment: Ps. @RapsFan1981: It might help if you told us what software you're actually using for the 3D modeling. You're not going to be able to rotate the photo in a 2D image editor, but you might be able to adjust the projection plane in the 3D software to account for the tilt.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hi there. I edited it in hopes of getting more responses, since the question was from Jul '12. 3D was out of scope at the time of the edit, so instead of closing it (and having misread it maybe) I focused it on 2D. Changed back, please re-edit if you feel you can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the image plane. Not sure how you've set it up and what program you are using, but if you can't rotate it, map the reference image to a plane with the same aspect ratio. Put it in the scene (behind the model) and rotate that instead. You will have to make your model transparent or semi-transparent to help you trace the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can either spend a long time in Photoshop mashing the face around into a front on image (which will never be perfect unless your one hell of a digital artist) or find another set of images and start fresh

But by far the best way to do it (which is how I was taught) was to take photo's ourselves, you get all the angles references etc... you need and if you take them of yourself and you realise you need more reference you can always take more.